# Every convergent sequence is relatively compact

Tags: hilbert-spaces, compactness

Let $X$ be an Hilbert space. It is known that:

1. Every bounded set is relatively compact (i.e., has compact closure) iff $X$ is finite dimensional
2. Every convergent sequence is bounded.
3. Every totally bounded set is relatively compact, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2641302/showing-that-a-totally-bounded-set-is-relatively-compact-closure-is-compact).

My question is: Does there exist an infinite dimensional $X$ such that every convergent sequence is relatively compact?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In any metric space, if $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is a convergent sequence and if $x=\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n$, then $\{x_n\,|\,n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is relatively compact, since its closure is $\{x_n\,|\,n\in\mathbb{N}\}\cup\{x\}$, which is compact.